# How to get array of unique objects with conditions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb

I have an array of objects.

I need to get an array with unique website name with newest date.

Sample data

```
"data" : [ 
{
    "position" : 2,
    "website" : "abc.com",
    "owned" : false,
    "date" : "2020-05-06",
    "dateTime" : ISODate("2020-05-06T00:00:00.000Z")
}, 
{
    "position" : 3,
    "website" : "qwe.com",
    "owned" : false,
    "date" : "2020-05-06",
    "dateTime" : ISODate("2020-05-06T00:00:00.000Z")
}, 
{
    "position" : 1,
    "website" : "qwe.com",
    "owned" : false,
    "date" : "2020-04-06",
    "dateTime" : ISODate("2020-04-06T00:00:00.000Z")
}, 
{
    "position" : 6,
    "website" : "xyz.agency",
    "owned" : false,
    "date" : "2020-05-06",
    "dateTime" : ISODate("2020-05-06T00:00:00.000Z")
}, 
{
    "position" : 4,
    "website" : "opq.com",
    "owned" : true,
    "date" : "2020-05-06",
    "dateTime" : ISODate("2020-05-06T00:00:00.000Z")
}, 
{
    "position" : 2,
    "website" : "opq.com",
    "owned" : true,
    "date" : "2020-05-06",
    "dateTime" : ISODate("2020-05-06T00:00:00.000Z")
},
{
    "position" : 4,
    "website" : "opq.com",
    "owned" : true,
    "date" : "2020-04-01",
    "dateTime" : ISODate("2020-04-01T00:00:00.000Z")
}
]
```

Based on datetTime, position  and website. Need a mongoDB query or Javascript code. (Earlier its with dateTime and website)

(Extracting the object from which have highest date and unique website name with top position)

Expected response

```
 "data" : [ 
{
    "position" : 2,
    "website" : "abc.com",
    "owned" : false,
    "date" : "2020-05-06",
    "dateTime" : ISODate("2020-05-06T00:00:00.000Z")
}, 
{
    "position" : 3,
    "website" : "qwe.com",
    "owned" : false,
    "date" : "2020-05-06",
    "dateTime" : ISODate("2020-05-06T00:00:00.000Z")
}, 
{
    "position" : 6,
    "website" : "xyz.agency",
    "owned" : false,
    "date" : "2020-05-06",
    "dateTime" : ISODate("2020-05-06T00:00:00.000Z")
}, 
{
    "position" : 2,
    "website" : "opq.com",
    "owned" : true,
    "date" : "2020-05-06",
    "dateTime" : ISODate("2020-05-06T00:00:00.000Z")
}
```

],

Comment: So `data` is an array field inside each document ? Or data is an array of docs ? Should we take `data` is an array field ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `forEach` and build an object to handle dulicates and maintain only new date item.
Get `Object.values` from above object.

```js
const uniq = (arr) => {
  const res = {};
  arr.forEach((item) => {
    if (
      !res[item.website] ||
      new Date(item.dateTime) > new Date(res[item.website].dateTime)
    ) {
      res[item.website] = { ...item };
    }
  });
  return Object.values(res);
};

// Update uniq2
const uniq2 = (arr) => {
  const res = {};
  arr.forEach((item) => {
    if (!res[item.website]) {
      res[item.website] = { ...item };
    } else {
      if (new Date(item.dateTime) > new Date(res[item.website].dateTime)) {
        res[item.website].dateTime = item.dateTime;
      }
      if (item.position > res[item.website].position) {
        res[item.website].position = item.position;
      }
    }
  });
  return Object.values(res);
};


const data2 = [
  {
    position: 2,
    website: "abc.com",
    owned: false,
    date: "2020-05-06",
    dateTime: "2020-05-06T00:00:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    position: 3,
    website: "qwe.com",
    owned: false,
    date: "2020-05-06",
    dateTime: "2020-05-06T00:00:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    position: 1,
    website: "qwe.com",
    owned: false,
    date: "2020-04-06",
    dateTime: "2020-04-06T00:00:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    position: 6,
    website: "xyz.agency",
    owned: false,
    date: "2020-05-06",
    dateTime: "2020-05-06T00:00:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    position: 1,
    website: "opq.com",
    owned: true,
    date: "2020-05-06",
    dateTime: "2020-05-06T00:00:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    position: 2,
    website: "opq.com",
    owned: true,
    date: "2020-05-06",
    dateTime: "2020-05-06T00:00:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    position: 3,
    website: "opq.com",
    owned: true,
    date: "2020-04-01",
    dateTime: "2020-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  },
];


console.log(uniq2(data2));
```

Comment: Is it   `new Date(item.dateTime) > new Date(res[item.website].dateTime)` ?

Comment: Oh yes I meant that. Good catch @ashwanth.

Comment: I just updated my question. Can you please check it. I have to make unique it with top position.

Comment: @AshwanthMadhav, Do you mean to say, for the one web site, need to extract the "latest date" and "top position" (position being small number)? Both attributes from the different objects?

Comment: If this is case, use `uniq2` method which I just updated in answer.

Comment: Returning   {
    position: 1,
    website: 'opq.com',
    owned: true,
    date: '2020-03-04',
    dateTime: 2020-05-06T00:00:00.000Z
  }, instead of  {
        "position": 3,
        "website": "opq.com",
        "owned": true,
        "date": "2020-05-06",
        "dateTime": new Date("2020-05-06")
    },`

Comment: Updated the answer. Check now? if still discrepancy, can you update the question with correct input data (Remove the ISOdate and keep the string) and expected output.

Answer (score 2):

In javascript you can `reduce` it:

```js
var data = [ { "position" : 0, "website" : "abc.com", "owned" : false, "date" : "2020-05-06", "dateTime" : 'ISODate("2020-05-06T00:00:00.000Z")' }, { "position" : 0, "website" : "qwe.com", "owned" : false, "date" : "2020-05-06", "dateTime" : 'ISODate("2020-05-06T00:00:00.000Z")' }, { "position" : 0, "website" : "qwe.com", "owned" : false, "date" : "2020-04-06", "dateTime" : 'ISODate("2020-04-06T00:00:00.000Z")' }, { "position" : 0, "website" : "xyz.agency", "owned" : false, "date" : "2020-05-06", "dateTime" : 'ISODate("2020-05-06T00:00:00.000Z")' }, { "position" : 1, "website" : "opq.com", "owned" : true, "date" : "2020-05-06", "dateTime" : 'ISODate("2020-05-06T00:00:00.000Z")' }, { "position" : 1, "website" : "opq.com", "owned" : true, "date" : "2020-04-01", "dateTime" : 'ISODate("2020-04-01T00:00:00.000Z")' }];

var result = data.reduce((acc, elem)=>{
  isPresent = acc.findIndex(k=>k.website==elem.website);
  if(isPresent==-1){
     acc.push(elem);
   } else {
     if(new Date(acc[isPresent].date) < new Date(elem.date)) acc[isPresent] = elem;
   }
  return acc;
},[]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Is it `isPresent = data.findIndex(k=>k.website==elem.website)` ?

Comment: @AshwanthMadhav No it will be `acc` which is accumulator of the `reduce` fn. where we will be checking if data is already there or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this- It also takes into consideration when the object is duplicate and dateTime are same/equal :

```
 var d = { "data" : [ 
{
    "position" : 0,
    "website" : "abc.com",
    "owned" : false,
    "date" : "2020-05-06",
    "dateTime" : "2020-05-06T00:00:00.000Z"
}, 
{
    "position" : 0,
    "website" : "qwe.com",
    "owned" : false,
    "date" : "2020-05-06",
    "dateTime" : "2020-05-06T00:00:00.000Z"
}, 
{
    "position" : 0,
    "website" : "xyz.agency",
    "owned" : false,
    "date" : "2020-05-06",
    "dateTime" : "2020-05-06T00:00:00.000Z"
}, 
{
    "position" : 1,
    "website" : "opq.com",
    "owned" : true,
    "date" : "2020-05-06",
    "dateTime" : "2020-05-06T00:00:00.000Z"
}
]
```

}

```
 var filtered = d.data.filter((el,idx)=> {
   let found = d.data.findIndex((e,i)=> e.website === el.website && idx !== i);

     return found === -1 ? el:Date.parse(el.dateTime) === 
          Date.parse((d.data[found]).dateTime)  && (found < idx) ? el: 
          Date.parse(el.dateTime) < 
          Date.parse((d.data[found]).dateTime) ? el: false
   });
```

console.log(filtered);